# Static std::vector in C++ function

Tags: c++, memory

I have a function `foo()` that declares a `std::vector` and uses it, such as:

```
int foo(int n, ... other args)
{
  vector<int> myVett(n);

  // foo is used for computation
}
```

`main()` calls `foo()` lots of times:

```
int main()
{
  //...

  for(int ii = 0; ii < 1e3; ii++)
      foo(n, ...)

  //...

 }
```

I would like `foo()` to avoid allocating memory for `myVett` at each iteration
of the `for()` loop.

I could allocate memory for `myVett` in `main()`, and then pass
it to `foo()`, but I would like to avoid that (because in my real example I have
several vectors `myVett1`, `myVett2`, etc. And I don't want to pass each of them
to `foo()` ).

At the moment I'm declaring `myVett` in `foo()` as `static`:

```
static vector<int> myVett(n);
```

Would this do the job? The application seems to run a bit faster, but I'm
not sure if I'm using the keyword `static` correctly.
Thanks!

Comment: Using a local `static` should usually be something of a last resort.  It makes your function non-thread-safe, and more difficult to test, as you now have implicit coupling between separate invocations.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any alternative to passing the vector from main()?

Comment: You have either the option of passing the vector to foo which you dont want. Other option is to put the foo method in a static class and make the vector a static class variable. It is preferable to avoid local static variable. If the program is multi threaded then you will issues with static approach.

Comment: This looks like a low level optimisation question. It is hard to give advices without knowing more of you context. At least do you want your code to be portable, or do you want to only optimize it for a specific compiler on a specific architecture?  Portable low level optimizations may not be possible, but if you only need a specific optimization  and if your implementation supports VLAs, a variable length array  could be faster than a vector (allocation only changes the stack pointer).